# Duplicate last row of certain sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with many sheets.

I'm trying to copy the last row with content to the next empty row in certain sheets.

For example my sheets are called Hoja1, Hoja2, Hoja3, ..., Hoja20 but I just need to do it in sheets Hoja1, Hoja3, Hoja4. Hoja12, Hoja13 and Hoja20.

This is my code:

```
Sub sale()

Sheets(Array("Hoja1", "Hoja3", "Hoja4", "Hoja12", "Hoja13")).Select
Sheets("Hoja20").Activate
Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Sometimes the last row is dropped and in Hoja3 when copy last row dropped last cell that in original row has data.

I tried this alternative:

```
Sub copylastrow()

Sheets(Array("Hoja1", "Hoja3", "Hoja4", "Hoja12", "Hoja13")).Select
Sheets("Hoja20").Activate

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

It copies the last row only in Hoja20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would divide this into a function that does the copy, and a client sub that establishes a collection of sheets and loops through them calling the copying function.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyLastRow(xlSheet As Worksheet)

    xlSheet.Activate
    xlSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy
    xlSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial

End Sub

Sub DoWork()
    Dim arrSheets As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet

    '// Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '// Establish the collection of sheets
    Set arrSheets = Sheets(Array("Hoja1", "Hoja3", "Hoja4", "Hoja12", "Hoja13"))

    '// Loop through each sheet and copy the last row
    For Each xlSheet In arrSheets
        CopyLastRow xlSheet
    Next xlSheet

    '// Turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As a side note, if you don't care about copying formatting of the last row, it might be better to simply assign the range value instead of using the Range object's `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` methods. You would do this like so:

```
Public Sub CopyLastRowFaster(xlSheet as Worksheet)

    xlSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow.Value = xlSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: @Sebastian Glad to hear it. If you get a moment, please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you :-)